# concerned that he is not working as hard as he should

Tags: meaning, word-usage

a. I am concerned that he is not working as hard as he should.

Does this mean that he is not working as hard as he should and I find that concerning, or does it mean I think he might not be working as hard as he should, and that is what concerns me?

I think for the second meaning we should have:

b. I am concerned that he might not be working as hard as he should.

Many thanks

Comment: Hi. The first sentence doesn't include the word "might", so why do you think it would mean that? Is there some context you failed to mention?

Comment: Thank you very much, No, there is no context. I just had doubts about the sentence because of the word 'concerned',

Comment: Concerned just means worried or anxious. It doesn't really say anything about the certainty of what one is worried about.

Comment: This ***is*** true. That ***might*** be true. See the difference?

Comment: Thank you both so much. I do see the difference, FumbleFingers, and that's why I asked the question.  I wanted to make sure that the same distinction existed when words like 'concerned' or 'worried' were involved.

Comment: I find that concerning = That is what concerns me.